# Are analytic functions in several variables open mappings?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, p-adic-analysis

It is well known that an analytic function $f$ defined on an open set $\Omega$ is an open mapping: for every open subset $U$ of $\Omega$, $f(U)$ is an open set of $\mathbb C$. Is this result still true in several variables? And in the $p$-adic setting (both in the single and several variables) ?

Comment: For several complex variables, see Theorem 1.8.1 and the paragraph after it in https://staff.fnwi.uva.nl/j.j.o.o.wiegerinck/edu/scv/scv1.pdf.  For several variables, did you want to assume the mapping is 1-1?

Comment: Not necessarly 1-1. Surjective is enough.

Comment: $(x,y)\mapsto (x,xy)$